Do all Fantasy Worlds Need Magic?
I am writing a high fantasy story, and I intentionally want practically no magic. Is it possible, or is it contradictory for a high fantasy world not to have magic?
If it is possible, how can I do it? How do I make a fantasy world distinctly fantasy, but distinctly not magical?

I’m voting to close this question for several reasons; it lacks clarity (several question into one), it belongs in my opinion on Writing.SE and not Worldbuilding, is probably opinion-based (lacks any metric to answer on). A case could be made if it is reworded, but understand that as is, it's very vague and probably not suited for this stack (or stacks in general).

Is the genre 'fantasy' still fantasy without magic?

What is a fantasy world? Why does it matter that the story takes place specifically in a >fantasy< world, whatever that is, and not in some plain ordinary >fictional< world? Why would the world of the Prisoner of Azakban (with magic) be considered more fantasier than the world of the Prisoner of Zenda (without magic)?

Your title asks a yes/no question with opposite direction as your body text. This results in confusing answers. Please change your body text to match title so yes and no have same meaning.

@SRM what do you mean? My apologies, new to this.

Look at the answer that starts “Sure”… the answer means, “sure it’s possible to do this”, but if you read your question in title and then answer it “sure”, it’s backwards.

The title asks whether all fantasy worlds need magic; answer: no, they don't. The body of the question asks whether it is possible for a high fantasy world not to have magic; answer: yes, it is. (And note that the title is about all fantasy worlds, and the body of the question is about specifically high fantasy worlds.)

@JBH See VLAZ link. Something similar has indeed been asked. But to your point, it's also why I said that I think it's opinion based (aka what are the expectations of fantasy and/or high-fantasy), unclear and "probably not suited for this stack (or stacks in general)"

@Nyakouai I do apologize. I was under the impression that they didn't answer questions like this. Glad I got my answer in, though. I consider the context of genre to be part of worldbuilding.

It will help if we get all our definitions straight
And this is important because even professors of creative writing often get stuck on a couple of concepts. Let's start with this:
The fantasy genre typically has no basis in scientific fact or speculation.
This is whomping important because most people will define fantasy like this:

Fantasy is a genre of literature that features magical and supernatural elements that do not exist in the real world. (Source)

This is not only ridiculously limiting, but we have to contend with Clarke's Third Law:

A sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

Which means, as @AlexP points out, Star Wars (and Star Trek and just about every other "science fiction" story you can think of) is fantasy. So, what makes fantasy, fantasy, in the context of your question?
Fantasy is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to a dragon, but that's just peanuts to fantasy. (Thanks Doug!)

If your story depends on technology reasonably extrapolated from what we know as technology today, it's Science Fiction. (Which is why Star Wars can be called science fiction — space ship propulsion is "science" even if it's the fantastic and unexplained "hyperdrive.")

If your story depends on people losing sleep because of what they read, it's probably Horror. Could be a textbook on modern American politics, but it's probably horror. Thus, while everything about H.P. Lovecraft's Cthulhu mythos is pure fantasy, the fact that it leaves readers feeling spooked makes it horror.

If your story depends on the drudgery of everyday life and the interrelationships involved with everyday life, it ain't fantasy. Unless it's making you warm and fuzzy, then it's likely Romance... which according to my wife is pure fantasy, but it doesn't involve orcs or stormtroopers so it's romance.

What's left over, with or without magic is fantasy. What differentiates historical fiction (a story of medieval knights fighting charming rogues who habitually give away their swag to the poor, for instance) from fantasy (a story of medieval knights riding north to fight a dragon)? I'll be honest with you, the answer is, the book industry and its incessant desire to create new genre. If the story lifts you out of your everyday problems and lets you dream big, it's fantasy. Everything else is a subgenre or non-fiction. (OK, I'm exaggerating a bit... but only a bit.)


And just to make things a little more complete
Let's make sure we understand what the subgenre "low fantasy" and "high fantasy" mean. (Click the source link below for a more complete list.)

Low fantasy. Set in the real world, low fantasy includes unexpected magical elements that shock characters, like the plastic figurines come to life in Lynne Reid Banks’s The Indian in the Cupboard (1980). (Source)


High or epic fantasy. Set in a magical environment that has its own rules and physical laws, this subgenre’s plots and themes have a grand scale and typically center on a single, well-developed hero or a band of heroes, such as Frodo Baggins and his cohorts in J. R. R. Tolkien’s The Lord of the Rings (1954).

Said another way, low fantasy is lower effort because the primary world — the Real World — has already been built for you and you're just adding a few things. High fantasy is higher effort because you took the time to imagine and develop the entire world.
But with all due respect to MasterClass... magic has nothing to do with it. They're using the word "magic" to describe world elements that don't have a scientific basis.
To be complete: what's a "scientific basis?"
This is more important than you might think. "Science" refers to knowledge that has been gained through (and this is really important) repeatable observation or experimentation.
Period!
Mathematics is not science. It's a tool of science. The fact that mathematically we predict the existence of dark matter does NOT mean dark matter is scientific. At best it's speculative science because until we've either repeatedly observed it (and not just the effects that suggest its existence) or experimented on it, it's not real. It is, in fact...
Fantasy.  AKA, science fiction.
Why was that painful truth important to say? Because anything and everything in your world that hasn't a scientific basis is "magical."
Because, obviously (and in the minds of too many people) the opposite of science is magic. The reason I loathe that conclusion is that it demands that a world that doesn't depend on science must have "magic" such as Wands of Lightning Strike.
Ptooey!1
What the creative masters mean by "magic" is "not dependent on science." So when you ask (and I only somewhat despair that it took so long to get to the answer to your question) if your fantasy (be it low or high!) can exclude magic the answer is both yes and no.
Yes: in that you needn't have Wands of Lightning Strike or mages or magical rings or (from a worldbuilding perspective) a magic system to write a great fantasy story.
No: in that a great fantasy story must be magical, meaning it must be capable of letting the reader's imagination take flight.
And that's why it's fair to describe Robin Hood as a low fantasy story. It's not historical. It's not "real." If you ignore the wonderful series Robin of Sherwood, it has no magic in it at all — but it's definitely a magical story. And that's fantasy.

1 In fact, let's make a point. Sometimes the difference between fantasy and science fiction is whether or not you, the author, bothered to explain the magic. Let's take Bank's The Indian in the Cupboard for instance. What makes that low fantasy but the plastic Autons of Dr. Who science fiction? Ms. Banks left how the plastic figurines became automated unexplained, making the mystery of their lives "magical" while the Dr. Who writers have explained that the plastic Autons are robots covered in plastic, making them machines and without mystery. Maybe after my lengthy post the idea can be easily summed as, "if you leave it a mystery and the story is still magical, it's fantasy. If you explain it and it doesn't jive with science to any degree, it's still fantasy. If you explain it scientifically or it's explicable via science, it's not fantasy." Cheers.


romance doesn’t involve orcs, oh, if only that were true


No
See: The Princess Bride
The closest thing we see to "magic" is Miracle Max, and even what he does, by his own admission, is basically reviving someone, not bringing them back from the dead.
But we have fencing, fighting, torture, revenge, giants, monsters, chases, escapes, true love...
And I would argue that it's items five and six that truly make it fantasy rather than just "adventure".  Weird megafauna (ROUSes!), and unusual humans.  Dwarves and giants are real things that people can be born with, but dwarven and gigantic communities are not, and that could be a part of making a magic-free fantasy setting.
In William Goldman's original, there were no Shrieking Eels, but there were the Cliffs of Insanity, and the Fire Swamps. Weird locations with stranger names.

Or the world of Conan the Barbarian. Or the works of H. P. Lovecraft. Or the world of Star Wars...

The subject line question is inverted from text. This answer should say “no” and body text get amended.

@SRM - good point.  Edited title.

Short answer: No, Fantasy worlds don't need Magic.
Long answer: it partially depends on what you consider magic or not.
Are dragons magic? or just large dinosaurs that never went extinct?
Dwarves and elves magical? or just different evolutionary paths where Dwarves evolved to be better in underground settings while Elves in a more densely forest setting.
Magic is something that used to explain things people could not understand. You can have your "magic" just be creatures that came to be to weird evolutionary circumstances and "powers" that stem from technological process.
If you would take fireworks back tot he past for 3000 years they would probably consider it magic simply because they have no other way of explaining it.
So as long as you can find a other way to explain it, then it doesn't have to be magic.

You may replace magic with alien intervention. Your society may be living in a controlled environment which appears to have some magical attributes. However, the characters in your story may be unaware of the aliens altering their surroundings as they please, at least in the society's early days. That society may think there is a magical power of some kind, if the aliens intervene and respond to "prayers" or magic rituals the society may develop over time.
